# Running tox on all interpreters including wide and narrow 2.7 compiled Python

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, tox, tox-globinterpreter

`ruamel.yaml` has a regression, introduced with a merged PR, that changed code that has essentially different paths for Python versions compiled with wide and narrow Unicode characters.

The regression was not found during the pre-build/commit testing, because the [tests](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/src/default/_test/), that are executed with [`tox`](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) were never run on a Python with narrow ('--enable-unicode=ucs2') Unicode characters. My 2.7.X is being  compiled with `--enable-unicode=ucs4' and in Python 3.4+ strings have dynamic Unicode width, acting as if they are 4 byte wide for the code involved.

I have compiled a narrow version of 2.7.15. *How can I test the narrow version along with the other Python versions (in particular the wide 2.7) in one `tox` run*, so that when one or more of the Python versions fail, no new version is committed, and no packages are pushed to PyPI?

I tried adding a target `py27m` to the interpreter list used by `tox-globinterpreter`:

```
p python2.7m /opt/python/2.7.15m/bin/python
```

and ran:

```
tox -r -e py27m
```

but that did not work, as that used Python 3.6.6 to run the test (which is the interpeter `tox` is executed with).

"Overloading" Python 2.6 in the interpreter list to use the narrow 2.7:

```
p python2.6 /opt/python/2.7.15m/bin/python
```

didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

That you cannot overload the interpreter list, probably has to do with dropped support for 2.6 (target `Python3.3` and using `tox -e py33` e.g. doesn't work either). But it is relatively easy to add a specific target for `py27m` in your `tox.ini`:

```
[tox]
toxworkdir = /data2/DATA/tox/ruamel.yaml 
envlist = py36,py27,py35,py34,pypy,py27m

[testenv]
commands =
    python -c "import sys, sysconfig; print('%s ucs-%s' % (sys.version.replace('\n', ' '), sysconfig.get_config_var('Py_UNICODE_SIZE'), ))"
    /bin/bash -c 'pytest _test/test_*.py'
deps =
    pytest

[testenv:py27m]
basepython = /opt/python/2.7.15m/bin/python
```

The `python -c ...` command is to have some extra feedback on the python version installed, in particular the character width, in each of the `virtualenv` enviroments `tox` creates, as the default `tox` output doesn't include that.
(The entries for running `flake8` / `codestyle` in the actual `tox.ini` were removed for clarity).

Together with a interpreter list (`~/.config/tox/interpreters.lst`):

```
v 1
# Original pattern used:
g /opt/python/?.?/bin/python?.? /opt/python/pypy2/bin/pypy 
# Interpreters found:
p python3.6 /opt/python/3.6/bin/python3.6
p python3.4 /opt/python/3.4/bin/python3.4
p python2.7 /opt/python/2.7/bin/python2.7
p python3.5 /opt/python/3.5/bin/python3.5
p python3.7 /opt/python/3.7/bin/python3.7
p pypy /opt/python/pypy2/bin/pypy
e
```

, running `tox -e` now results in:

```
.
.
.
2.7.15 (default, Jun 30 2018, 23:05:50)  [GCC 7.3.0] ucs-4
py27m runtests: commands[1] | /bin/bash -c pytest _test/test_*.py
============================= test session starts =============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.15, pytest-3.6.2, py-1.5.4, pluggy-0.6.0
.
.
.
2.7.15 (default, Jul  1 2018, 11:43:51)  [GCC 7.3.0] ucs-2
py27m runtests: commands[1] | /bin/bash -c pytest _test/test_*.py
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.15, pytest-3.6.2, py-1.5.4, pluggy-0.6.0
.
.
.
============= 320 passed, 1 skipped, 7 xfailed in 32.36 seconds ===============
___________________________________ summary ____________________________________
  py36: commands succeeded
  py27: commands succeeded
  py35: commands succeeded
  py34: commands succeeded
  pypy: commands succeeded
  py27m: commands succeeded
  congratulations :)
```

This way code paths that differ for the same Python version compiled with narrow and wide Unicode can be tested in one go.